# Load an Image into RGBA array C++

Tags: c++, image, converters

Is there a way to load an Image into an three dimensional int Array with the RGBA data for every pixel ?
for example pixel at 60,20 is black I want the array at [60][20] to be 0,0,0,100

Comment: You mean if there is a standard function or library in the language for that? If so, the answer is no. There are many third party libraries that do this, though. Here is one: http://www.imagemagick.org/

Comment: What format is the "image".

Comment: Your example indexes a 3D array with 2D syntax. You mean you want [60,20,0] to be 0, [60,20,1] = 0, ..., [60,20,3] = 100.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done that a while back when working on video because the video frames would always be 640x480 (NTSC).

You can just declare the RGBA as a structure:

```
struct rgba {
    unsigned char red;
    unsigned char green;
    unsigned char blue;
    unsigned char alpha;
};
```

Then you declare your array as in:

```
rgba image[640][480];
```

(note: you probably want to inverse the height and width, I'll let you discover why...)

The load becomes something like:

```
file.read(image, sizeof(image));
```

That, of course, means the file data is in the right format: i.e. raw RGBA in the same "endian", etc. In most cases that's not how images are saved on disk, though.

As mentioned by glampert, one library is ImageMagick. You could also make use of a specific loader for JPEG, PNG, GIF87a... However, in all those cases you are not likely to be able to load the image directly in your array. You'd need a copy from some Image object buffer to your array.

So say you use a library that gives you an object, maybe something like this:

```
Image img;
img.load(filename);
memcpy(image, img.data(), sizeof(image));
```

This is very basic code, you should test that the load() worked, that the format is right and that the width x height are right too.